# Jquery load function throws "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed" error in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Trying to load an xml file and getting the xml parsing error.

```
$("#analyticForm_description").load('https://192.168.23.10/SystemServices/main?system:run=html/indicators/templates/editApp-definition.xml&Id=1000205&palletId=testtt', function() { MD.ui.editPallets.editform_definition(); } );
```

Should not throw any error. Note the url provided is valid and accessible from a browser directly. The function is also being called. Somehow even after the error reported on console, page loads successfully.

Do not want to see any errors reported on console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Firefox expects an Content-Type and Chrome ignores it.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "https://192.168.23.10/SystemServices/main?system:run=html/indicators/templates/editApp-definition.xml&Id=1000205&palletId=testtt",
    contentType: "text/xml",
    success : function(response) {
        $("#analyticForm_description").html(response);
    }
});
```

or for the load method use [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/):

> Description: Set default values for future Ajax requests. Its use is
>   **not recommended**.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  contentType: "text/xml"
});

$("#analyticForm_description").load('https://192.168.23.10/SystemServices/...', function() { 
  MD.ui.editPallets.editform_definition();
});
```

Comment: Is there any possible way to add contentType to the Jquery .load() function. Unfortunately I should not change this line to ajax call. :(

Comment: I've expanded my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem was with the xml templates response content-type. Changed it, to match the requestor's content type.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing a similar error and upon search i stumbled upon this post, after debugging code for a while i found out the reason.

Error shown in console

```
XML Parsing Error: undefined entity
Location: path-to-file.html#link3
Line Number 26, Column 29:
```

**Here is why i was getting this error**

I was dynamically generating url that i want to hit, and due to some typo i was getting `undefined` as the url which was used in making ajax calls resulting in this issue

```
$.ajax({
    url: url, //this was undefined
    type: "get",
    data: data,
    contentType: "text/xml",
    success: function (response) {
        //some code
    },
});
```

***Posting this as it might help someone facing the same issue.***